# How to make Rmarkdown output as markdown with code chunk results in blocked quotes (instead of tab)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I want to have a .md file with "code result" contained in backtick quotes.

For example,

The example Rmd file is as follows:

````
---
title: 
output:
  md_document:
    variant: commonmark
---

```{r}
print(1:100)
```
````

and rendered .md file is as follows:

````
``` r
print(1:100)
```

    ##   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
    ##  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
    ##  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
    ##  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
    ##  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
    ##  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
````

but I want to have md file with

````
``` r
print(1:100)
```

```
##   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
##  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
##  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
##  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
##  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
##  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```
````

Is there any way to alter the md output's code output from tabbed to back-tick?